# Approximate range detection

Tags: machine-learning

I have a setup that is similar to cocktail problem. There is a microphone array (includes 5 microphones in a line-10 cm spaces each) attached to a wall. I am driving a rc toy car in front of the array and getting audio data for each microphone. Then importing this dataset to a realtime histogram and trying to get the approximate range for the rc toy car. I have tried some methods for to get range (triangulation, least squares, regression ...) but for all of them visualised realtime range data is bouncy, not stable. Some of them are less bouncy but bouncy, not stable.

Which machine learning algorithms or statistical methods fit well for this problem? I'd like to hear your ideas.

I am newbie and not sure I have asked this question to the right community, but if anyone lead me to the right point regardlessly,I fully appreciate.

Edit:
gif1-far

[image: range2]

gif2-close

[image: range1]

UPDATED:

--gif-far

[image: far]

--gif-near

[image: near]

Comment: A standard approach would be [Recursive Bayesian estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_Bayesian_estimation), using a Kalman filter or particle filter for data assimilation. An accessible introduction is [this](https://www.udacity.com/course/artificial-intelligence-for-robotics--cs373) free Udacity course. The basic approach would be to synthesize noisy observations with an evolution model, e.g. use the car's velocity to predict the next position (both noisy estimates themselves).

Comment: Thanks very much @GeoMatt22 especially for Udacity course but your solution looks much complicated for my problem. I might not express my problem well. There are simple gif noiseless implementations. Blue ones are microphones and its values, red one is car, green one is range and orange one is road width. Closer the car to the mic array, bigger values on mics. For the transition areas, sound value is being shared according to the position of mics. Actually I need a function that I will replace the variables with mic values and get the approximate value (green ones) not the exact metric value.

Comment: Are your GIFs realistic? I would think the acoustic response would be something like a decaying function of car-to-mic distance? (in the simplest model, ignoring obstacles/reflections) Your GIFs seem to have very anisotropic sound attenuation. I would think, given the inter-mic spacing relative to the distance of car from the top, that more than 2 mic's should be getting a response simultaneously. The whole inference depends on this "measurement function", including 1) the deterministic aspects, and 2) the "signal to noise ratio".

Comment: The gifs are not realistic. You are right about acoustic decaying and more than 2 mics are getting the response at the same time in practice.But to discuss on solution, you can exclude detailed parameters and you can think acoustic response is like more column than as wave to adapt the problem as the gifs. I am on to identify what kind of problem I am facing and its solution on statistical,maths or computer science literature.

Comment: If your mic's are showing a time-varying signal, then there is attenuation: this seems like a key part of the model, needed for inference. Not knowing too much about the physics, I would say [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Inverse-proportional_law) is a reasonable default model: On average the mic response should be inversely proportional to distance from the car. Ignoring vertical distance, you would be able to get the distance from two mic's, if 1) there is no noise, and 2) you know the source intensity + attenuation coeff. The stats is to deal with those uncertainties.

Comment: If you update the question with your model, we can try to advise on adjusting it to deal with noise more smoothly.

Comment: Vertical distance you mentioned isn't the range,is it?  Good point with the model. The model reminds me [lever moment equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever#/media/File:Lever_Principle_3D.png). It makes sense when you observe the motion in the GIFs. Pivot position gives the X position of the car and  pivot height will give us the range.What do you think?

Comment: Still working on the problem.The setup with mics was very noisy.So I have updated the setup with infrared sensors.Same arrangement...Five elements in an array,but with IR sensors for this time.New GIFs are the samples of realtime IR sensor readings from five IR sensors.Any suggestions for appropriate model to detect approximate range data?Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.